# Redirect with get_context_data in generic detailview django

Tags: django, redirect, django-models

I have this view where i needed two models Book and UserFav so I used context for that:

```
class BookDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = Book
    template_name = 'book_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BookDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'fav_list': UserFav.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        })
        return context
```

and another view function

```
def favorite(request, pk):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=pk)
    fav, created = UserFav.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    fav.favorites.add(book)
    return render(request, 'book_detail.html', {'book': book})
```

form for the favourite function

```
<form action="{% url 'favorite' book.id %}" method="post" style="display: inline;">
{% csrf_token %}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>&nbsp; add this book to favourite
</button>
```

my url

```
url(r'^book/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.BookDetailView.as_view(), name='book-detail'),
url(r'^book/(?P<pk>\d+)/f/$', views.favorite, name='favorite'),
```

where I need fav_list

```
{% if fav_list %}
{% for fav in fav_list %}
{% if book in fav.favorites.all %}Favorited
{% else %}
<form action="{% url 'favorite' book.id %}" method="post" style="display:inline;">
{% csrf_token %}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>&nbsp; add this book to favourite
</button>
 </form>
 {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
 {% else %}
 <form action="{% url 'favorite' book.id %}" method="post" style="display: inline;">
{% csrf_token %}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>&nbsp; add this book to favourite
</button>
                                </form>
 {% endif %}
```

now the problem is that when i get redirected to book_detail.html I am not getting the fav_list which is needed for the template
How do I redirect properly or use some other way to define views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not redirecting from the `favorite` view. Upon form submission, considered a good practice to redirect.

**Try**

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import reverse

def favorite(request, pk):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=pk)
    fav, created = UserFav.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    fav.favorites.add(book)
    # if you have an app_name in urls.py file try this
    # return redirect(reverse('YOUR_APP_NAME:book-detail', args=(pk,)))
    return redirect(reverse('book-detail', args=(pk,)))
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: gives error: Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/book/5/f/book_detail.html

Comment: Anyother way to declare url for this function? Then it may work

Comment: same error: Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/book/7/f/book/book-detail its works with the render but only not getting the fav_list object

Comment: @Ahmed ok, it doesn't know how to resolve the path, I edited my answer, used the `reverse` method. Check it out